# Changing common default parameter in all functions in a package

Tags: r

I would like to write a function which "resets" the default values to a parameter common throughout all R functions in a package.

Is this possible?

what I've thought up is this, but this just returns a list of curried functions:

```
library(magrittr)

function(parameter){ 
   ls("package:packageName") %>%
   lapply(function(fxnName){
      functional::Curry(get(fxn), paramOfInterest = parameter)
   }
}
```

Pipe `%>%` from the `magrittr` package.

I guess one caveat of doing it this way is losing the documentation.

Perhaps I could solve this by referring to an attribute modifiable and stored in an object in the package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it would be possible to do this by assigning to the global environment, the following is neater in my opinion since the default behaviour can easily be restored by `detach`ing the environment:

First some demo functions since I don't know which package you wanted to use:

```
packageDemo <- new.env()
makeFun <- function(x) {x;function(param) c(x, param)}
for (i in paste0("f", letters)) assign(i, makeFun(i), packageDemo)
```

Now here's my curry package function. It takes either an environment or a package name as a character vector (e.g. `"package:myPackage"`). All of the functions in the environment are curried and added to a new environment which is returned. This can then be `attach`ed if needed.

```
curryPackage <- function(package, ..., functionNames = NULL){
  if (is.character(package) && !grepl("^package:", package)) {
    package <- paste0("package:", package)
  }
  fnNames <- ls(package)
  if (!is.null(functionNames)) {
    fnNames <- fnNames[fnNames %in% functionNames]
  }
  fnNames <- fnNames[vapply(fnNames, function(x) is.function(get(x, package)), logical(1))]
  fnList <- lapply(fnNames, function(x){
    functional::Curry(get(x, package), ...)
  })
  names(fnList) <- fnNames
  list2env(fnList)
}
```

Now some demos

```
attach(packageDemo)
fc("Testing")
#[1] "fc"   "Testing"
fc()
#Error in fc() : argument "param" is missing, with no default

newPack <- curryPackage(packageDemo, param = "demo")
attach(newPack)
#The following objects are masked from packageDemo:
#
#    fa, fb, fc, fd, fe, ff, fg, fh, fi, fj, fk, fl, fm, fn, fo, fp, fq, fr, fs, ft, fu, fv, fw, fx, fy, fz
fc("Testing")
#Error in (function (param)  : unused argument ("Testing")
fc()
#[1] "fc"   "demo"
```